# Magento - Admin manage products grid ajax search returns the whole page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

When I click the search button on the Manage Products page in the admin of my Magento store the ajax call returns the whole page and places it inside the grid area of the initial page and the "Please wait..." modal/image never disappears.

For some reason the search ajax POST request returns a 302 response which is different to another one of my Magento stores that works correctly which returns a 200.

See screenshot below

[image: Magento Admin Search - Window within a window]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what error you get in console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The ajax post returns a 302 to the same page which loads inside the original page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following function to the grid class

```
 public function getGridUrl()
 {
   return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
 }
```

Add a "gridAction" method to your admin controller

```
 public function gridAction()
 {
   $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
       $this->getLayout()->createBlock('{Namespace}/adminhtml_{Module}/grid')->toHtml()
); 
 }
```

Comment: thanks, I assume my Magento is using the standard grid class and admin controller for the product grid in which case these methods are already there. All other grids ajax search work correctly just not the product list one. If my product list is not using the standard code how can I find out which files are being used?